# Bose 2 Bluetooth headset doesn't show in Dragon Naturally Speaking 12 Audio Devices

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth, dragon-naturally-speaking

System specs:

- Windows8 Pro with Media Center
- 3 GB RAM
- 2 TB HDD

All drivers are current.

When I first installed Windows 8 Pro I also installed Dragon Naturally Speaking 12 (DNS12) and a Bluetooth dongle. I was able at that time (last fall) to turn on my Bose 2 headset, have it appear in the DNS12 Audio Devices list, and use it with DNS12. I then decided to use the Bose 2 with my cell phone for a few months. Now I am unable to get it to appear in DNS12. It shows up in the Device Manager, has the current drivers, and shows as "Working Properly". So, Windows 8 says that it's there, but that's the extent of it.

I spoke with Bose technical support, and they tell me that I have done everything correctly. During my attempts, I uninstalled DNS12 and the Bluetooth dongle, cleaned the registry, and reinstalled everything, but without success.

Any ideas as to how to get it working again?

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem setting my Bose Series 2 with a Windows 8 tablet.  It turned out I had paired it with my phone first and there is a different paring procedure for devices after the first one.  The call / large push button on the Bose needs to be pushed for about 5 seconds while paring it to devices after the first device.